# google appengine data store storage on reloading the webpage

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I wrote this simple which inputs a username and saves to the data store. But the problem I face is, every time I reload the result page("Welcome user") the same username is again stored in the datastore with a different key. How can I prevent the username to be stored into the datastore when reloaded?

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import db


#form is a simple html file which takes an input.



class Name(db.Model):
    username = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write(form)
    def post(self):
        username = self.request.get('username')
        self.response.out.write("Welcome"+str(username))
        user1 = Name(username=username)
        user1.put()



application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

PS: Kindly forgive me for the below comments!

Comment: The C++11 header is just `unordered_map`. You're using like C++07 stuff.

Comment: Remove the `tr1/` in the include, and the line `using namespace std::tr1;`. And while you're at it, it would be better to remove the line `using namespace std;` as well, and properly qualify the names.